# Parse through Json response using rest-assured

Tags: json, rest, web-services, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I want to parse through my JSON response to validate the response i obtained.

```
 [
    {
        "Emp": "00000",
        "Emp_ID": 901,
        "First_Name": "agar",
        "Last_Name": "vedi",
        "Country": "India",
        "EmpLocation": "Noida"
    },
    {
        "Emp": "001",
        "Emp_ID": 383,
        "First_Name": "Manoj",
        "Last_Name": "jee"
        "Country": "India",
        "EmpLocation": "Noida"
    }
]
```

Now , I am using Rest-assured java API for this ,
I went through the tutorial on toolsQA and their they are using

```
Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.GET, "/Hyderabad");
```

For the Json:-

```
{
    “City”: “Hyderabad”,
    “Temperature”: “31.49 Degree celsius”,
    “Humidity”: “62 Percent”,
    “Weather Description”: “scattered clouds”,
    “Wind Speed”: “3.6 Km per hour”,
    “Wind Direction degree”: “270 Degree”
   }
```

Now this response is a single JSON object.
But mine is nested in a JSON Array .

How do I parse through such nested Json objects and arrays ? as Json response can come in all combinations of Array and Objects .

Is their a method in rest-assured which provides value corresponding to the key?
example:     "key":"value"
I go to the key and obtain the value through that method?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use Groovy Gpath: http://james-willett.com/2017/05/rest-assured-gpath-json/

Answer (score 1):

If you have mapped the JSON to PoJo, you just need to change the request to:

```
City[] cities = given()
                    .when()
                    .get("/Hyderabad")
                    .then()
                    .response()
                    .getBody()
                    .as(City[].class);
```

This is how RestAssured can deserialize an array of objects. You need to map it to Array of Objects.